# Image is not rendering

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to display a local image in my Xamarin.Forms app, but for some reason I can not see it. I saved `hawk.jpg` under `Assets/` in the core project and in the Android project under `Ressource/Drawable/Assets`.

This is how I try to display the image

```
new Image
{
    Source = "Assets/hawk.jpg",
    Aspect = Xamarin.Forms.Aspect.AspectFill,
    WidthRequest = 200,
    HeightRequest = 200
}
```

Comment: From my understanding, the path for Android should be `Resources/drawable`, not `Resources/Drawable/Assets` (see this sample project https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages.Android/Resources/drawable) Have you tried updating that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Assets/` from the source. This should resolve your issue. Also make sure the image is marked as a resource in your Xamarin project (right click the image and it will be under the file type).